# NestedScrollView cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have ConstraintLayout inside of ScrollView.
I'm trying to use ConstraintLayout animation. It works perfect outside of ScrollView but when I want to use it inside ScrollView the AndroidStudio says:

```
android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

I know its because my root layout is ScrollView but I don't know how to fix this.

I tried to add another ConstraintLayout before ScrollView, this time the APP worked without crash, but when I press the button nothing happens.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/const1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

This is what i did in MainActivity

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_animation);
ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
transition.setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator(1.0f));
transition.setDuration(1200);
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cc1, transition);
constraintSet.applyTo(cc1);
```

Comment: Can you show your declaration for cc1?

Comment: I also believe you are trying to clone constraints for your whole layout but NestedScrollView does not have constraints. You need to clone the constraints for cc1(if that is your constraintLayout) not for the whole layout.

Comment: ^ Basically, that. The `clone(Context, int)` method assumes that the root `View` in the provided layout is a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: @brandonx   Yes.  here it is:    ConstraintLayout cc1= findViewById(R.id.inputUser);

Comment: Try cloning cc1 without the context parameter, rather than your whole layout. I also don't see that you are changing anything that would trigger a changeBounds transition. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MikeM. is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Arashreyhani clone(ConstraintLayout constraintLayout)

Comment: @brandonx I want to when i click on add button some EditText appear , so user can insert some data to add to database.

Comment: @Arashreyhani I think there is some confusion as to how transitions work. For a simple changeBounds transition you shouldn't be cloning your constraints and then reapplying them to your layout. Changing a constraint or otherwise changing the size of the ConstraintLayout programmatically after calling beginDelayedTransition is what will trigger an animation. Someone correct me if I am wrong, but cloning your constraints seems unnecessary here.

Comment: @brandonx sorry i did what u said:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference

Comment: @brandonx it works perfectly everyWhere except on ScrollView.

Comment: @Arashreyhani What it comes down to is that you cannot clone the constraints of a view that does not have constraints like NestedScrollView. You tried constraintSet.clone(cc1)?

Comment: @brandonx this time: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3305180: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe3303310), and nothing happens.

Comment: @Arashreyhani that is unrelated and I believe if you solve that, this will work.

Comment: @brandonx I remove the ScrollView of the second xml and it worked. but on return :    private void revertAnimation() {
        show = false;

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(c1);

        ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator(1.0f));
        transition.setDuration(1200);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(c1, transition);
        constraintSet.applyTo(c1);

    } it do nothing and I'm confused.

Comment: @Arashreyhani can you show your code for how you are binding view to variables.

Comment: @brandonx can u please take a look to my last question?

Comment: It does nothing because you are aren't doing anything to the view that would change it's bounds. I would recommend reading up on transitions. Cloning a view's constraintSet and then reapplying it to the view will not do anything unless the view has changed constraints in between those calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below code

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_animation); //this line need to be changed to 
constraintSet.clone(this, const1);// Pass id of ConstraintLayout for cloning as root layout of your xml file is not a ConstraintLayout.
```

Comment: i did that before not working.I had to remove ScrollView. Fortunately still scrolling.

Comment: Or else you can add ConstraintLayout as parent of ScrollView means as a root View

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could try if you don't mind animating all layout changes within your views. It's easy enough to add and see if it works for your use case. Add:

```xml
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

to your NestedScrollView and turn off all of your transitions. Any time you change the bounds of a view or bring something new on or off screen android will handle animations automatically. Again YMMV as you can't control the speed, etc of the animations but it is worth a try.